# app is installed but not launching on my emulator

Tags: android

> In my emulator app installed successfully but app is not launching ,here i am pasting the console details 
>   here i am adding manifest file as well ,i added intent-filter as well.
>   i hope this info is enough but stackoverflow needs some more info .

```
 [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] Android Launch!
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] adb is running normally.
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] No Launcher activity found!
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] Performing sync
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'AVD_4.0'
    [2012-12-13 20:29:52 - PongUr2] Uploading PongUr2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2012-12-13 20:29:53 - PongUr2] Installing PongUr2.apk...
    [2012-12-13 20:30:00 - PongUr2] Success!
    [2012-12-13 20:30:01 - PongUr2] \PongUr2\bin\PongUr2.apk installed on device
    [2012-12-13 20:30:01 - PongUr2] Done!
```

Hereś the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sabrebutt.pongur"
    android:versionCode="49"
    android:versionName="0.8.8.2" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <service
            android:name="PongUr"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="1" >
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/pongur" />
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="PongUrSettings"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/pongur_settings"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
     />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: Have you tried to open the app from the emulator's app drawer after it has been installed? Or is it just not launching after you launch from IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your activities have launcher intent filter, Add below lines to the activity you want to launch in your manifest

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Edit:
You cannot have an intentfilter inside an intentFilter and the launcher intent filter will not work on service, only Activities can be launched and can have UI

```
   <activity
        android:name="PongUrSettings"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/pongur_settings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: dont put on the wallpaperservice, put it on the activity

Comment: if you don't mine could you suggest me any live wallpaper sample project plz.

Comment: never worked on live wallpaper, but i guess there is one in sample app that comes with android sdk

Comment: could you forward it to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try going `Setting -> Application(apps) --> uninstall your app` & run again your app . May be it should work.Sometimes previous installation creates this type problem.Otherwise may be problem with your menifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to this particular error. When app is installed and not launched, you can check the 'Launch options' in 'Run Configuration'. It should be selected as 'Default Activity'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).